# Issue with else statement when reading lines

Tags: java

So what i have to do is Read from a file and have the user input HR followed by some numbers if the input is found it will print out the line that the input is located i have all that sorted but my problem is my else statement if the HR Code is not found it will print out that it the input was not found but my problem is even if the number they entered was located it will print out the else statement for all of the lines that don't have the number in it. (sorry im shit at explaining stuff) but anyway here is the code.

don't know if this is easier to understand but what i want to do is if the input is found then print out the line, that works fine. But what i need to do is. if the input is not found then i want it to print out that the Input was not found in the file, but i don't want it to print out for every line that is in the file

```
package Assignment;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Planets1 {


    public static void main( String [ ] args )
    {
        {
            File file =new File("stars1.dat");
            Scanner in;

            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter HR code : ");

            String userInput = keyboard.nextLine();
            try {
                in = new Scanner(file);
                while(in.hasNext())
                {
                    String line=in.nextLine();
                    if(line.contains(userInput.toUpperCase()))
                        System.out.println(line);
                    else if(!line.contains(userInput.toUpperCase()))
                        System.out.println("No Planet with the HR code: " + userInput.toUpperCase() + " Was found.");

                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
    }
}
```

and what it is outputting if the code is found:

Enter HR code :

**Hr 897**

Acamar;Theta 1 Eridani;HR 897

No Planet with the HR code: HR 897 Was found.

No Planet with the HR code: HR 897 Was found.

No Planet with the HR code: HR 897 Was found.

No Planet with the HR code: HR 897 Was found.

No Planet with the HR code: HR 897 Was found.

No Planet with the HR code: HR 897 Was found.

Comment: Not sure if this is going to solve your issue, but some advice: 1) add `{}` around your `if` and `else if` bodies. 2) You can make your `else if(...)` a simple `else`.

Comment: 3) Why are you using `hasNext()` for the loop condition but `nextLine()` within? You know there is `hasNextLine()`, right?

Comment: 4) If you want to print nothing for lines without a match, why not just remove the whole `else if` part entirely? I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do though...

Comment: 5) The first few and the last line of your code are not properly formatted in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if . . . else if` is being executed for every line in your input file.

So, if a line in the file matches your input HR Code, the line is printed.

But for all of the other lines that **do not** match the HR code, the "No Planet . . . Was found" message is printed.

You need to wait until **after processing all lines in the file** before deciding whether to print the "No Planet . . . Was found" message:

```
boolean found = false;
while(in.hasNext())
{
    String line=in.nextLine();
    if(line.contains(userInput.toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println(line);
        found = true;
    }
}
if (found == false) {
    System.out.println("No Planet with the HR code: " + userInput.toUpperCase() + " Was found.");
}
```